# Kendo Combobox Change event fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I have Kendo Combobox in that on Change event I am calling a controllers action using Jquery Ajax.For the first time on Select of any item from Combobox the Action is called and I get the required data.
But on ComboxBox focus Out(When i click on any where on the screen) the same action is being called.
My Kendo Combobox is as follows:

```
$("#Number").kendoComboBox({
                        dataTextField: "NUM",
                        dataValueField: "ID",
                        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: ResolveUrl("/CreateMaintainAnalysis/GetAnalysisNumbers/"),
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: function () {
                                        return {
                                            Number: $("#Number").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
                                        };
                                    }
                                },

                            },
                            requestEnd: function (e) {
                                if (WebApp.CLAF.LoggedInUser.Info.IS_ANALYST == 'Y') {
                                    e.response.unshift({ ID: -1, NUM: 'Create New Analysis' });
                                }
                                else {
                                    e.response.unshift({ ID: -2, NUM: 'Select' });
                                }
                            },
                            serverFiltering: true
                        }),
                        filter: "startwith",
                        suggest: true,
                        minLength: 5,
                        highlightFirst: true,
                        index:0,
                        change: function (dataItem) {
                              $.ajax({
                                 type: "POST",
                                 data: { ID: ID },
                                 url: ResolveUrl("/Analysis/Data"),
                                 success: function (result) {
                                 },                 
                                });
                         }
                      });
```

This is really very weird behavior and I am not able to catch it up.

Comment: Can you make it happen here http://dojo.telerik.com/UziZo ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown...Here thats working as expected..may be some invalid code that is inserted on the page..Need to Investigate..but not able to find it

Comment: I mean, your code looks good. Can't tell what could be your issue with only this snippet. If you could add more of your code, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Inside dataSource please add `autoBind: false`, this is by default true, and most often this is the reason for sending an additional API call from inside upon any focus in/out or click events.